# Postgresql Columns information from schema including descriptions

Tags: database, postgresql, schema

I need to connect from all tables in a data base some column information, I found this select

```
SELECT 'postgresql' AS dbms,
        t.table_catalog,t.table_schema,
        t.table_name,c.column_name,
        c.ordinal_position,c.data_type,
        c.character_maximum_length,
        n.constraint_type,
        k2.table_schema,
        k2.table_name,
        k2.column_name

FROM information_schema.tables t 
    NATURAL LEFT JOIN information_schema.columns c 
        LEFT JOIN(
            information_schema.key_column_usage k 
                NATURAL JOIN information_schema.table_constraints n 
                NATURAL LEFT JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints r) 
        ON c.table_catalog=k.table_catalog 
        AND c.table_schema=k.table_schema 
        AND c.table_name=k.table_name 
        AND c.column_name=k.column_name 
    LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k2 
        ON k.position_in_unique_constraint=k2.ordinal_position 
        AND r.unique_constraint_catalog=k2.constraint_catalog 
        AND r.unique_constraint_schema=k2.constraint_schema 
        AND r.unique_constraint_name=k2.constraint_name 
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND t.table_schema NOT IN('information_schema','pg_catalog')
ORDER BY t.table_name;
```

This query offerme a lot information but I need the description for all columns names.

I found this other query that show me the descriptions

```
SELECT *

FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_all_tables as st
        inner join pg_catalog.pg_description pgd on (pgd.objoid=st.relid)
        inner join information_schema.columns c on (pgd.objsubid=c.ordinal_position
                and  c.table_schema=st.schemaname and c.table_name=st.relname);
```

The question is how can I insert the field **pgd.description**  from the second query into the first query.

Thanks and regards
Curro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're two different sets of metadata functions: the first uses the universal information_schema, whilst the second uses PostgreSQL's specific system functions. They can be joined by obtaining the object id (oid) from the schema and tablename from the information_schema tables:

```
SELECT 'postgresql' AS dbms,
        t.table_catalog,t.table_schema,
        t.table_name,c.column_name,
        c.ordinal_position,c.data_type,
        c.character_maximum_length,
        n.constraint_type,
        k2.table_schema,
        k2.table_name,
        k2.column_name,
        td.description AS table_description,
        cd.description AS column_description
FROM information_schema.tables t
    LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_description td
        ON (td.objoid = (quote_ident(t.table_schema)||'.'||quote_ident(t.table_name))::regclass AND td.objsubid = 0)
    NATURAL LEFT JOIN information_schema.columns c 
        LEFT JOIN(
            information_schema.key_column_usage k 
                NATURAL JOIN information_schema.table_constraints n 
                NATURAL LEFT JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints r) 
        ON c.table_catalog=k.table_catalog 
        AND c.table_schema=k.table_schema 
        AND c.table_name=k.table_name 
        AND c.column_name=k.column_name 
    LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k2 
        ON k.position_in_unique_constraint=k2.ordinal_position 
        AND r.unique_constraint_catalog=k2.constraint_catalog 
        AND r.unique_constraint_schema=k2.constraint_schema 
        AND r.unique_constraint_name=k2.constraint_name 
    LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_description cd
        ON (cd.objoid = (quote_ident(t.table_schema)||'.'||quote_ident(t.table_name))::regclass AND cd.objsubid = c.ordinal_position)
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND t.table_schema NOT IN('information_schema','pg_catalog')
ORDER BY t.table_name;
```